# Swift 4 Get results in completion handler

Tags: swift

I have a method that is making a call to another method that has a completion handler.

```
func getFilesAndDirectories(folder:String) -> Array<Dictionary<String, String>>
    {
        var returnedResults = Array<Dictionary<String, String>>()

        WebService().GetFilesAndDirectories(folder)
        {
            (result: Array<Dictionary<String, String>>) in

            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                returnedResults = result

            }

        }

        return returnedResults
    }
```

Here is how I am calling it:

```
var filesDirectories = Array<Dictionary<String, String>>()

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        filesDirectories = getFilesAndDirectories(folder: "/")
        print(filesDirectories)
    }
```

But when I print filesDirectories it returns []

My question is, how do I get the results from getFilesAndDirectories to filesDirectories?

Comment: Use yourself a closure because your call seems to be async.

Comment: How do I do that @Larme

Comment: Your `getFilesAndDirectories` function returns before your WebService has finished its request to the server. Your `getFilesAndDirectories` function should pass in a closure that you can call from within your WebService closure once it has finished.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
func getFilesAndDirectories(folder:String, completionHandler:@escaping (_ result:Array<Dictionary<String, String>>) -> Void)
{
    var returnedResults = Array<Dictionary<String, String>>()

    WebService().GetFilesAndDirectories(folder)
    {
        (result: Array<Dictionary<String, String>>) in

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            returnedResults = result

            completionHandler(returnedResults)
        }
    }
}
```

And you can use the same as follows

```
var filesDirectories = Array<Dictionary<String, String>>()

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    getFilesAndDirectories(folder: "/") { result in
        self.filesDirectories = result
        print(filesDirectories)
    }
}
```

Comment: Same result....print(filesDirectories) in viewDidAppear is empty...I know that data is coming from the call, cause if print after this line returnedResults = result, it will print my result, but this is not working,.

Comment: This fails because the call to `completionHandler(returnedResults)` is in the wrong place.

Comment: Yes it was...I moved the completionHandler(returnedResults) right after returnedResults = result I added a print after this: getFilesAndDirectories(folder: "/") { result in
            self.filesDirectories = result
        } its still blank, but when I move the print inside it works.

Comment: I would like to use the variable after I get the data.

Answer (score 2):

You could do some thing like this:

```
func getFilesAndDirectories(folder: String, completionHandler: @escaping (_ result: Array<Dictionary<String, String>>) -> ()) {

    WebService().GetFilesAndDirectories(folder) {
        (result: Array<Dictionary<String, String>>) in
            completionHandler(result)
        }
}
```

and then:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    getFilesAndDirectories(folder: "/", completionHandler: ({
    (result) in 
        print(result)
    }))
}
```

You should have the right value inside the completionHandler scope.

Comment: This does work, but when I try to assign the result into this var filesDirectories = Array<Dictionary<String, String>>(), it says afterwards its empty :(

Comment: How do I assign the results to a variable so I can use that variable

Comment: This answer is correct. You just have to assign `result` to `filesDirectories` inside the completion handler.

Comment: @user979331 It's been several years since you asked this question. Did you ever get a clear, working solution? I am experiencing the exact same issue now and I can't seem to find an answer. I know it's a concurrency issue, but I am not sure what design pattern to use to solve it.